# Can I somehow make at print the hostname in the email with output?

Tags: 16.04, at-command

I'm using `at` to run some commands. The output is emailed to the email-address in `$HOME/.forward`. But the problem is that nowhere in the email that is sent does it say which host had the issue (I have three hosts, dev, stage and prod).

I could print the hostname in the beginning of every job I run with `at`, but that would cause `at` to send an email even when the actual command doesn't have any output.

Is there some way I can configure the way `at` sends email? Perhaps configuring the subject line? Or the `From` header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mail headers (in Thunderbird: "view - message source" or Ctrl-U) you should see from where the mail originated, e.g.

```
Return-Path: <jean@myAcer>
X-Original-To: jean@myAcer
Delivered-To: jean@myAcer
Received: by myAcer.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id B2E23A11E3; Fri, 15 Mar 2019 20:16:50 +0100 (CET)
```

If not, take a look at your postfix configuration in '/etc/postfix/main.cf'. There should be a line 'myhostname = ...'.

Comment: In my case it was the `masquerade_domains=` setting in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` that hid the domain.